# Error while configuring EMS with Database in Fault Tolerant mode

Tags: tibco, fault-tolerance, ems

I am trying to setup my EMS in FT Mode, I have configured all the parameters in the 2 EMS config files.
But Im getting the warning:

**Unable to initialize fault tolerant connection, remote server returned 'invalid user name'**

Servername and password are exactly the same in both config files,so I don't know where the error is.

I am attaching the EMS config files that i am using for the EMS servers:

```
tibemsd.conf:

authorization = enabled
password =
server=EMS-HakanLAL
listen=tcp://7222
Ft_active=tcp://8222

users                   = users.conf
groups                  = groups.conf
topics                  = topics.conf
queues                  = queues.conf
acl_list                = acl.conf
factories               = factories.conf
routes                  = routes.conf
bridges                 = bridges.conf
transports              = transports.conf
tibrvcm                 = tibrvcm.conf
durables                = durables.conf
channels                = channels.conf
stores                  = stores.conf

store                   = "C:/temp"


tibemsdft.conf:

authorization = enabled
password =
server=EMS-HakanLAL
listen=tcp://8222
Ft_active=tcp://7222

users                   = C:\Tibco\ems\8.1\BackUp\users.conf
groups                  = C:\Tibco\ems\8.1\BackUp\groups.conf
topics                  = C:\Tibco\ems\8.1\BackUp\topics.conf
queues                  = C:\Tibco\ems\8.1\BackUp\queues.conf
acl_list                = C:\Tibco\ems\8.1\BackUp\acl.conf
factories               = C:\Tibco\ems\8.1\BackUp\factories.conf
routes                  = C:\Tibco\ems\8.1\BackUp\routes.conf
bridges                 = C:\Tibco\ems\8.1\BackUp\bridges.conf
transports              = C:\Tibco\ems\8.1\BackUp\transports.conf
tibrvcm                 = C:\Tibco\ems\8.1\BackUp\tibrvcm.conf
durables                = C:\Tibco\ems\8.1\BackUp\durables.conf
channels                = C:\Tibco\ems\8.1\BackUp\channels.conf
stores                  = C:\Tibco\ems\8.1\BackUp\stores.conf

store                   = "C:\ProgramData\TIBCO3\tibco\cfgmgmt\ems\data"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your tibemsd.conf and tibemsdft.conf looks fine. What you are probably missing is registering the server-name as a user within the users.conf.
If you make that entry, both servers should be able to connect to each other.